# Getting label text of checkbox and appending to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on revamping some old code and needing some help on this last addition. Basically can have a variable number of checkboxes and need to get the labels text to any of those checkboxes and append that text to another div. Have rewritten this a ton of times and used a lot of others code but nothing seems to be working. Have seen several similar questions on here but none of those have worked for a solution to this problem.

Problem:
Get a **labels text** associated to it's **input checkbox**. Then once that text value is gathered append it to a separate div.

Note:
The checkboxes have an ID and a VALUE that are the same because of some different code versions just trying to get them to work. Would like a solution using VALUE only.

HTML:

```
<a cid="38" href="javascript:void(0);" class="cat_filter">
  <div class="cat-filter_checkbox">
    <input class="cat_filter_checkbox" name="" type="checkbox" value="38" id="38">
    <label for="38">Category ONE</label>
  </div>
</a>
<a cid="14" href="javascript:void(0);" class="cat_filter">
  <div class="cat-filter_checkbox">
    <input class="cat_filter_checkbox" name="" type="checkbox" value="14" id="14">
    <label for="14">Category TWO</label>
  </div>
</a>


 <div id="labelName"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".cat_filter").live('click', function() {
    $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
    var labelName = $(this).find("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").text();        
    labelName.appendTo('#labelName');        
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/o25z9w0f/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question reads like a homework assignment. On a side note, avoid creating your own attributes and use the custom data attribute instead. So `data-cid="38"` instead of `cid="38"`.

Comment: The reason it reads like that is because there's a specific problem and it's trying to reflect that. The cid is associated to another part of the code that's not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this should solve your problem:

```js
$(".cat_filter").on('click','input',function() {
//On click on an input field. if this isn't OK tell me and I will change it again.
       $('#labelName').html($('label[for='+$(this).prop('id')+']').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a cid="38" href="javascript:void(0);" class="cat_filter">
    <div class="cat-filter_checkbox">
        <input class="cat_filter_checkbox" name="" type="checkbox" value="38" id="38">
        <label for="38">Category ONE</label>
    </div>
</a>
 <a cid="14" href="javascript:void(0);" class="cat_filter">
     <div class="cat-filter_checkbox">
             <input class="cat_filter_checkbox" name="" type="checkbox" value="14" id="14">
             <label for="14">Category TWO</label>
     </div>
</a>
<div id="labelName"></div>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: @Full-Hybrid: If you don't need the `<a href..>`s and `<div>`s I can change the two input fields so that your example should work without them.

Comment: Just put in the snippet and is working great thank you so much! The other surrounding code has other functionality attachments so wanted to leave that intact.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('input[type ="checkbox"]');
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
for (node in nodeList) {
    div.innerHTML += node.text; //or label if you set that attribute on the element
}
```

Does not rely on jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the help, wanted to rely on jQuery because that's how it was originally written and have to blend things together.

Comment: Just because this one instance doesn't rely on `jquery` doesn't mean you can't use `jquery` elsewhere in your app. Sometimes the natives are actually clearer/less verbose.